# Printing the value of 2 functions one near the other

Tags: functions

I have 2 functions, one is set in a custom plug in, the other in functions.php

```
$pulizia_esc = get_the_author_meta( 'pulizia_esc', $post->post_author );
if ( ! empty( $pulizia_esc)) {
$pulizia_esc = '<div class="pulizia_esc">'. $pulizia_esc .'</div>';
}
```

and

```
function pulizia_meta_box_render( $post ){
$number = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "function_pulizia", true );
echo '<div><input type="number" name="function_pulizia" value="'.$number.'" placeholder="Costo pulizia" /></div>';
}
```

I must write the value of each function one near the other, so that, first I'll have as output "final cleaning" and than the amount of final cleaning, i.e.: 50, and than adding € as postfix

T tryed with

```
$pulizia_esc = get_the_author_meta( 'pulizia_esc', $post->post_author ), get_post_meta( $post->ID, "function_pulizia", true ) ;
if ( ! empty( $pulizia_esc)) {
$pulizia_esc = '<div class="pulizia_esc">'. $pulizia_esc .'</div>';
}
```

and with

```
$pulizia_esc = get_the_author_meta( 'pulizia_esc', $post->post_author );
$number = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "function_pulizia", true );
if ( ! empty( $pulizia_esc)) {
$pulizia_esc = '<div class="pulizia_esc">'. $pulizia_esc . $number . € '</div>';
}

enter code here
```

But none of the 2 experiments works. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Right code:

```
$pulizia_esc = get_the_author_meta( 'pulizia_esc', $post->post_author ) . ' ' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, "function_pulizia", true ) ;
if ( ! empty( $pulizia_esc)) {
$pulizia_esc = '<div class="pulizia_esc">'. $pulizia_esc . ' euro' .'</div>';
}
```